Sketching Angular Momentum Vector Field
The following is a question from the book Gravitation by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler. They define the angular momentum vector in Euclidean Space by the formula $L_j=\epsilon_{jkl}{x^k}\frac{{\partial}}{\partial{x^l}}$ and are asking to find the commutation relations. I managed to do it analytically, but have two doubts: first, they are also asking me to sketch these vector fields and find the commutator from there as well. How to go about this? I did read the box in the book which mentions this, but am unable to figure out a way to represent it pictorially, owing to the partial derivative in there.
Second, is the notation above for $L_j$ (which is given in the book) incorrect, as it does not use the correct summation convention? Or is it ok (as I have assumed while proving the relations analytically), because we are only dealing with Euclidean geometry?
